# Facebook android API function executeGraphPathRequestAsync not giving expected results

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to discover if a user likes a specific facebook page by using Graph API inside an android application using the FB SDK v3.

The following call works and reports all of the likes of the user along with every other detail to do with each resulting item.

```
Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(session, "me/likes", new Request.Callback()
```

Since I'm not interested in any peripheral data, I just want to get the id back so I can lookup the page I'm interested in, but when I add the parameters as follows...

```
Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(session, "me/likes?fields=id", new Request.Callback()
```

... no object is returned from the call.  If I post the same queries in the Graph API explorer they give back the expected results.

In addition to this question, is it at all possible to limit the result of the query to just the page ID to begin with, since I already know that piece of information?  I have no use for the rest of the data being returned and would prefer not to chew up user bandwidth unnecessarily.  I've searched high and low and it doesn't seem possible.  Even the FQL explorer doesn't work when trying to limit by both user and page iD as the example suggests.  I get an empty result set when adding 'AND page_id=xxx' to the query.

Answer (score 6):

As far as i know, you cant run queries with field in 'executeGraphPathRequestAsync'.
instead use 'Request' and run in with 'RequestAsyncTask'.
Short example:

```
        String grapPath = "me/home";

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "type,id,object_id,created_time,from,picture,likes");
        params.putString("limit", "500");

        Request request = new Request(session, grapPath, params, HttpMethod.GET, new Callback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response)
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG_NAME, "response: " + response.toString());
                }

            }
        });

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
```

Hope i managed to help you :)

Comment: BTW, you can also use this to post data. simply vhange the method to POST. just dont forget to add the  needed permissions.

Answer (score -1):

The Facebook SDK will add the "?access_token" to the end of the graph path string.  So the graph command ends up looking like:

```
me/likes?fields=id?access_token
```

Break out the fields into a params Bundle.

Found this issue resolved in a Facebook bug post:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/314504765319932?browse=search_5116b87d245900257505334